# What does this C# code mean?

Tags: c#, .net

```
FunctionThatReturnsAList(cmd)[0]
```

Comment: Can you please give some more description about it?

Comment: This is one of those times that a function name could use CamelCase or some_underscores...

Comment: I had to double take the name of this function because I thought it was 'function whore turn list' as opposed to 'function who return list' :)

Comment: At first I thought this was a joke, like ExpertS-exChange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is short-hand for:

```
List<Whatever> list = FunctionThatReturnsAList(cmd);
Whatever whatever = list[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `FunctionThatReturnsAList` is an object, like a List or an array that can be accessed via an indexer. The code is calling the function, which is then returning the List or array and then using the indexer to reference the first element in the collection.

An example would be:

```
var cmd = "123";

var returnedObj = FunctionThatReturnsAList(cmd)[0];

private List<string> FunctionThatReturnsAList(cmd)
{
    return new List<string> {cmd};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a list, and you just access element 0 in the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like cmd is an SQL command which returns may be array of some kind like DataTable[] and this function gets only first element(DataTable) from the array.

Comment: WOW!!!! That is impressive! Now quickly, what lottery numbers are coming up next week?

Answer (score 0):

This statement can be used for all methods whose return type has a numeric indexer (e.g. lists or arrays).